# Set display order for product images imported programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

During my testing of magento, I have been able to import products into the store by reading XML. My XML also contains an array of image URLs associated with the product. I read the URL in each image property, download it and move it into the media/import folder. I then associate each image to the product

```
foreach($mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName)
{
    try {
         $product->addImageToMediaGallery($fileName, $imageType, false, false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The one thing I would like to fix is decided a sort order of the images, and which one is the default image that is displayed on page load. Is there a way to programmatically say I want this file to be the first image to display? The one that magento it showing on page load isn't the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below allows you to import images and set the position. It will set the position based on the order of the images in your array so you would need to change that if that is not what is required but hopefully this will at least give you an idea of how it can be done.

```
$sku = $product->getSku();
$media = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api');

$position = 1;
foreach($mediaArray as $fileName) {

    if (file_exists($fileName)) { // assuming $fileName is full path not just the file name
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($fileName);

        switch($pathInfo['extension']){
            case 'png':
                $mimeType = 'image/png';
                break;
            case 'jpg':
                $mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $mimeType = 'image/gif';
                break;
        }

        $types = ($position == 1) ? array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail') : array();
        $newImage = array(
            'file' => array(
                'content' => base64_encode($fileName),
                'mime' => $mimeType,
                'name' => basename($fileName),
                ),
            'label' => 'whatever', // change this. 
            'position' => $position,
            'types' => $types,
            'exclude' => 0,
        );

        $media->create($sku, $newImage);
        // OR (if you would rather use the product entity ID):
        // $media->create($productId, $newImage, null, 'id');
        $position++;
    } else {
        // image not found
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, there is a position field. I thought there might be a parameter to say "default image" on a per product basis. This should work fine, thanks.

Comment: I get an error thrown "not_created" on the $media->create() statement. Also, is there a way to change the default image in the admin UI? Sometimes the order isn't what I want, so I just want to change it through the UI.

Comment: In that case I would try to put some debug code into the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Media_Api class. If you don't know already, you'll find it in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php. You should be able to narrow down where the fault is occurring that way. Just remember to revert any changes made to the core code afterwards. And yes, this can be changed manually in the Images section of a product (Catalog -> Manage Products).